# Rails app JavaScript not working when placed in application.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app. The JavaScript works perfectly when it is included in the index.html.erb view in a script tag. The JavaScript doesn't work at all when I place it in my application.js file.

Here is my entire application.js file. This code does not work:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .


var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
```

This exact same code works perfectly when included in a script tag in the actual view:

```
<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

Can someone help me figure out why this is happening? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not being run because its not being included in the compiled `application.js`. You can verify this by looking at the source of the javascript file in the browser.

You need to add `require_self` to the sprockets manifest which injects the contents of the file itself:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require_self
//= require_tree .
```

You only need to do this for your main "manifest" file as files required by `require_tree .` are of course included.

See:
- [The Assets Pipeline - 2.4 Manifest Files and Directives](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives)